# PHP rounding issue - Is this a bug?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Floating point inaccuracy examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples)

If i say round(152.77499999999998,2) the answer becomes 152.78. Should it not look at the 3rd number after the decimal point and if it is 5 or higher round up and if it is 4 or lower round down, hence the answer should be 152.77?

Thanks

Comment: Canned response: inherent flaw in all binary floating point systems.

Answer (score 1):

You should do:

```
round(152.77499999999998 * 100)/100
```

to get the exact number! :)

Answer (score 1):

It is very possible that in whatever internal representation  152.77499999999998 gets folded to it is actually more like 152.77500001754…; and hence the rounding goes up.

Answer (score 0):

What php is going is regular rounding.

This same question was asked here 2 years ago:
http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=247953 (what are the chances?)

Comment: Asymptotically approaching 1.